# Execute PHPUnit Testcases from PHPStorm using Lando

Tags: docker, phpunit, drupal-8, lando

I've successfully configured the PHPStorm with the Docker containers served by Lando. Still, when I'm trying to execute the test, for instance, the `core/modules/system/tests/src/Functional/System/HtaccessTest.php` it's throwing me the following error:

```sh
Testing started at 1:00 AM ...
[docker://devwithlando/php:7.2-apache-2/]:php /opt/project/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --configuration /opt/project/phpunit.xml --filter "/(Drupal\\Tests\\system\\Functional\\System\\HtaccessTest::testIndexphpRewrite)( .*)?$/" --test-suffix HtaccessTest.php /opt/project/core/modules/system/tests/src/Functional/System --teamcity
PHPUnit 6.5.14 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Testing /opt/project/core/modules/system/tests/src/Functional/System

Drupal\Core\Installer\Exception\AlreadyInstalledException : <ul>
<li>To start over, you must empty your existing database and copy <em>default.settings.php</em> over <em>settings.php</em>.</li>
<li>To upgrade an existing installation, proceed to the <a href="/update.php">update script</a>.</li>
<li>View your <a href="http://my-lando-app.lndo.site">existing site</a>.</li>
</ul>
 /opt/project/core/includes/install.core.inc:534
 /opt/project/core/includes/install.core.inc:114
 /opt/project/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Test/FunctionalTestSetupTrait.php:296
 /opt/project/core/tests/Drupal/Tests/BrowserTestBase.php:573
 /opt/project/core/tests/Drupal/Tests/BrowserTestBase.php:406



Time: 22.67 seconds, Memory: 6.00MB


ERRORS!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.

Process finished with exit code 2
```

I made a wild guess the issue could have been with the database connection, hence I've tried with all the following options i.e.:

```xml
mysql://drupal8:drupal8@database:3306/drupal8
mysql://drupal8:drupal8@database/drupal8
mysql://drupal8:drupal8@localhost:32860/drupal8
<!-- 32860 is nothing but the port for external_connection. -->
```

```xml
  <php>
    <!-- Set error reporting to E_ALL. -->
    <ini name="error_reporting" value="32767"/>
    <!-- Do not limit the amount of memory tests take to run. -->
    <ini name="memory_limit" value="-1"/>
    <!-- Example SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL value: http://localhost -->
    <env name="SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL" value="http://my-lando-app.lndo.site/"/>
    <!-- Example SIMPLETEST_DB value: mysql://username:password@localhost/databasename#table_prefix -->
    <env name="SIMPLETEST_DB" value="mysql://drupal8:drupal8@database:3306/drupal8"/>
    <!-- Example BROWSERTEST_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY value: /path/to/webroot/sites/simpletest/browser_output -->
    <env name="BROWSERTEST_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY" value="/app/sites/simpletest/browser_output"/>
    <!-- To have browsertest output use an alternative base URL. For example if
     SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL is an internal DDEV URL, you can set this to the
     external DDev URL so you can follow the links directly.
    -->
    <env name="BROWSERTEST_OUTPUT_BASE_URL" value=""/>
    <!-- To disable deprecation testing completely uncomment the next line. -->
    <!-- <env name="SYMFONY_DEPRECATIONS_HELPER" value="disabled"/> -->
    <!-- Example for changing the driver class for mink tests MINK_DRIVER_CLASS value: 'Drupal\FunctionalJavascriptTests\DrupalSelenium2Driver' -->
    <env name="MINK_DRIVER_CLASS" value=''/>
    <!-- Example for changing the driver args to mink tests MINK_DRIVER_ARGS value: '["http://127.0.0.1:8510"]' -->
    <env name="MINK_DRIVER_ARGS" value=''/>
    <!-- Example for changing the driver args to phantomjs tests MINK_DRIVER_ARGS_PHANTOMJS value: '["http://127.0.0.1:8510"]' -->
    <env name="MINK_DRIVER_ARGS_PHANTOMJS" value=''/>
    <!-- Example for changing the driver args to webdriver tests MINK_DRIVER_ARGS_WEBDRIVER value: '["chrome", { "chromeOptions": { "w3c": false } }, "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"]' For using the Firefox browser, replace "chrome" with "firefox" -->
    <env name="MINK_DRIVER_ARGS_WEBDRIVER" value=''/>
  </php>
```

I'm also attaching the output of my `lando info` command, just in case if it's helpful:

```sh
[ { service: 'appserver',
    urls:
     [ 'https://localhost:32861',
       'http://localhost:32862',
       'http://my-lando-app.lndo.site/',
       'https://my-lando-app.lndo.site/' ],
    type: 'php',
    healthy: true,
    via: 'apache',
    webroot: '.',
    config: { php: '/Users/rishi/.lando/config/drupal8/php.ini' },
    version: '7.2',
    meUser: 'www-data',
    hostnames: [ 'appserver.mylandoapp.internal' ] },
  { service: 'database',
    urls: [],
    type: 'mysql',
    healthy: true,
    internal_connection: { host: 'database', port: '3306' },
    external_connection: { host: '127.0.0.1', port: '32860' },
    healthcheck: 'bash -c "[ -f /bitnami/mysql/.mysql_initialized ]"',
    creds: { database: 'drupal8', password: 'drupal8', user: 'drupal8' },
    config: { database: '/Users/rishi/.lando/config/drupal8/mysql.cnf' },
    version: '5.7',
    meUser: 'www-data',
    hostnames: [ 'database.mylandoapp.internal' ] } ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run

```sh
$ docker network ls
```

Then copy the "network id" for the "appserver".

Now, lets update your PHPStorm settings. Go to "Languages > PHP > Test Frameworks"

[image]

Then click the folder icon next to the "Docker Container" definition.

[image]

Now, change the `Network Mode` to your `network id` that you copied at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks, Josh  Your solution worked like charm! I would like to add that it even works if I'm using `NETWORK NAME` instead of `NETWORK ID`.

Comment: I posted a more detailed write up here: https://github.com/lando/lando/issues/2232